# How to use Groovy dynamic objects to call methods requiring concrete types (without referencing them)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, classloader

Given the following code:

```
def model = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
dep = [
   groupId : "org.foo",
   artifactId :  "bar",
   version : "1.0" ]
```

I would like to call [`Model.addDependency`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/ModelBase.html#addDependency(org.apache.maven.model.Dependency))

```
model.addDependency(dep)
```

This gives the error

> Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.maven.model.Model.addDependency() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[groupId:org.foo, artifactId:bar, version:1.0]]

Now it is possible to do

```
model.addDependency(dep as Dependency)
```

When referencing the class. And it works without problems. locally.

Unfortunately, I have to execute that on Jenkins, and I am running into this [issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40514?focusedCommentId=292649&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-292649). So basically, if I reference the `Dependency` class, I running into some class loading issues. There is a recommendation to use "dynamic typing".

So it is possible to call `addDependency` without referencing that class?

Comment: It seems impossible. You need either create a `Dependency` object or cast an instance of `Map` to it.

Comment: I can't think of an easy way for me to test this, but try this. I'll convert it into an answer if it works. With any luck, parameterTypes will pull out the Class resolved from Model's classloader rather than the script's own.
> model.addDependency(model.&addDependency.parameterTypes[0].newInstance(dep))

Comment: @Corrodias: So this basically means to access that class via reflection? It might work, but unfortunately I can't test that right now because the code runs in a groovy sandbox on Jenkins which does not allow that methods, I will have to wait until it is approved by an admin. (maybe on monday)

Comment: @Corrodias:  your solution works, so if you create an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the classloader that loaded the Model class (let's call it "A") is not the same one as the script tries to use when you refer to the Dependency class ("B"). So you can create a Dependency-B with your classloader-B, but a Model-A demands a Dependency-A.

We can use reflection to get a reference to the Dependency-A class, then create an instance of it using the same property map, like so:

```
def model = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
dep = [
   groupId : "org.foo",
   artifactId :  "bar",
   version : "1.0" ]
model.addDependency(model.&addDependency.parameterTypes[0].n‌​ewInstance(dep))
```

In Groovy, &addDependency is a method reference, reflection style. We know for certain that there's only one method by that name and it has only one parameter, so we just take the first parameter's class and call newInstance, which works the same way as the "as" keyword would have.

Answer (score 0):

I created a ticket for that https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-70717 . Thanks for the workaround, I added that there.