# Add dependency to Maven pom file using org.apache.maven.Model

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy

I’m trying to add dependency to maven pom.xml file using approach described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46781493/3481377)…

```
def model = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
dep = [
   groupId : "org.foo",
   artifactId :  "bar"
   ]
model.addDependency(model.&addDependency.parameterTypes[0].newInstance(dep))
```

…but I’m facing an error which sounds like:

```
Groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Class.newInstance() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[groupId:org.foo, artifactId:bar]]
Possible solutions: newInstance(), newInstance(), newInstance([Ljava.lang.Object;), isInstance(java.lang.Object)
```

What am I doing wrong? I spent 7 days for now trying to fix this thing and add dependency to pom file, but no luck. The only emergency exit here is to replace file contents using shell script, but it’s the least wanted solution. Yes, I can also parse xml file using groovy methods, but it’s not what we wanted, too.

Comment: Why are you adding dependencies on a CI server? Why are those dependencies not part of the pom already ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, we develop jenkins job which can build multimodule project based on list of modules we want to have in it. so I'm asking for it because I want to be able to dynamically assembly pom file in pipeline script.